# Impute missing value for dummy variables in R by ratio of non_missing value

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I am a new learner in R. Now, I made a trouble in imputing missing value and need your help. I have a data frame df like this:

```
a  <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,NA)
b  <- c(1,0,1,0,1,0,NA)
c  <- c(0,1,NA,0,1,0,1)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

I would like to impute the missing value of these variables according to the ratio of non NA value. For example: variable a has 50% of 0 and 50% of 1. So, NA value should be impute to 0 and 1 to keep the ratio the same. 
Here are my code:

```
    ratio0 <- function(x) {  # ratio 0 of non NA missing value
           table(x)[1]/sum(table(x)[1],table(x)[2])
    } 
    ratio1 <- function(x) {  # ratio 1 of non NA missing value
           table(x)[2]/sum(table(x)[1],table(x)[2])
    } 

    for(i in 1:ncol(df)) {
        df[is.na(df[,i]), i] <- sample(c(0,1),sum(is.na(df[,i])),replace=TRUE,prob=c(ratio0(df[,i]),ratio1(df[,i])))
    }
```

When applying the code above, I got the error: "Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : NA in probability vector".

Could you please let me know where my mistakes ?

Because when I try to apply code for a single variable, it works. For example, the code below to impute the missing value of the 3rd column of the dataframe df.

```
df[is.na(df[,3]), 3] <- sample(c(0,1), sum(is.na(df[,3])), replace=TRUE, prob=c(ratio0(df[,3]), ratio1(df[,3])))
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you share the expected output? Are you replacing one `NA` value by two?

Comment: I want to replace NA value by 0 or 1. In the dataset, for example: variable a has 500 NA value. These 500 NA value should be replaced by 0 or 1. The ratio of 0 and 1 depends on the ratio of 0 and 1 in non NA value.

Comment: you mean the probability of the replacement, as in your example the ratio will be changed with both replacement 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make a ratio function I would do somthing like this

```
ratio <- function(x, which) {
    b <- !is.na(x)
    sum(x[b] == which) / sum(b)
}
```

but if I understood you correctly you could use the vector of not na values to sample from it directly

```
fun <- function(x) {
    b <- is.na(x)
    x[b] <- sample(x[!b], sum(b), replace=TRUE)
    x
}

as.data.frame(lapply(df, fun), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks Florian. I applied your code and it works well. However, could you brief me a little bit about how the code works ?

Comment: is.na(x) will return TRUE for every NA value, you can use vectors of type logical to index other vector or lists.

so b is a vector of type logical 
the sum(b) gives you the number of NA values, so 

     x[b]
     gives you the na values and
     sample(x[!b], sum(b), replace=TRUE)
     gives you a vector sampled from the non na values of the length of the na value (sum(b))

if you use lapply on a data.frame it will apply the function on every column and return a list of the results and you can turn that again into a data.frame by using as.data.frame

Comment: or in code examples 
`y <- c(0, 1 , NA, 1, 1, 0, NA, 1)` 
`is.na(y)`
`y[!is.na(y)]`
`sum(is.na(y))`

Comment: Thanks Florian. I got the idea of the second one. But, how's about the ratio function ? What the role of "which" here? I still do not get it. Sorry, if I asked a stupid question. :-(

Comment: the which is just so you can get the ratio of both 0 and 1 with one function
ratio(a, which=0) or ratio(a, which=1) in your case

Answer (score 1):

We could construct a custom function and consequently `apply()` it to your `data.frame` columnwise.

```
# Function to replace NA's
replacer <- function(x) {

probs <- prop.table(table(x)) # Get proportions
y <- sample(c(0,1),length(which(is.na(x))), prob = probs, replace = TRUE)# Generate sample
x[is.na(x)] <- y # Replace values
return(x)

}

> apply(df,2,replacer)
#     a b c
#[1,] 0 1 0
#[2,] 0 0 1
#[3,] 0 1 1
#[4,] 1 0 0
#[5,] 1 1 1
#[6,] 1 0 0
#[7,] 1 1 1
```